# Access database in VB2013 Community

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm a little confused on the way **VB** handles **Access** databases in my project. Can someone set me straight, please?

The original db is in my project folder. It's my understanding that setting the property to "copy if newer" will copy THAT database to the debug/bin folder so that when I run debug, any changes I made to the tables directly from the Access interface will be recognized and reflected in that copied version. That seems to be not happening completely.

I opened the db in Access and added two fields to a table. Then I opened my VB project and looked in Server Explorer to see if the table did in fact show the new fields. It did. However, when I open the form that has that table bound to a **DGV** on that form, the fields do not show up.

I looked at the DGV properties, specifically columns/collection and the two new fields do now show there either. I'm confused as to why they show in Server Explorer but not elsewhere.

Perhaps it comes down to the way VB recognizes or doesn't recognize that a change has been made to the DB in the Projects folder. With that thought in mind I changed the DB properties to "copy always" but still the fields don't show. I changed it back to "copy if newer" and again the fields are not visible at the form level but do show in Server Explorer.

I need to get this figured out so that as I progress with the project, I can edit the DB tables directly as needed and be able to see them in the project.